# What function does the series converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I'm trying to find the function this series converges to.
$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty}{{{n+i}\choose{n}}{(\frac{a}{x})}^{i}}$

I guess it converges to $(\frac{x}{x-a})^{n+1}$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct question? I can move $(a/x)^n$ in front of the series, after which we clearly see that the series diverges.

Comment: @Stockfish You're right. Thank you. The power of $a/x$ must be $ i $. I edited it.

Comment: Start replacing $\frac a x$ by $y$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you, and then?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2431627.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah. Thanks. I don't know how to thank you 

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 2):

By binomial theorem for any non-naturalindex, we have
$$(1+z)^\nu=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\nu \choose k} z^k.$$
Let $z=-x$ and $\nu=-n$, then
$$(1-x)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-n \choose k} (-x)^k$$
Now use the property that $$={-\nu \choose k}=(-1)^k {\nu+k-1 \choose k}$$
We get $$\sum_{k=0} {n+k-1 \choose k} x^k=(1-x)^{-n}$$
Replace $n$ by $n+1$ both sides, to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n+k \choose k} x^k=(1-x)^{-(n+1)}$$
So in your case $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {n+i \choose i} (a/x)^i=(1-a/x)^{-(n+1)}=\left(\frac{x}{x-a}\right)^{n+1}$$